# How to speed up pie charts creation in VB Web?

Tags: vb.net

I have a web page that can create multiple pie charts based on an SQL query that executes when the page is loading. However I have noticed that the page loading takes too long (around 30 seconds). I checked the SQL formula and can confirm that it is working fine (results given almost instantly).

There are 40 different pie charts the page needs to create, and the page also have the option to generate a single pie chart and that works fast enough.

So I can deduce that it's the pie chart generation that is slow when it needs to create 40 of them. Is there a way to help speed up the pie chart creation process?

Here is my code for reference.

```
 Sub draw_chart1() 'All Machines

    Dim check1, check2, fi, cnt

    Dim sql
    Dim myConnectionString As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & SQLDB_pp.ConnectionString
    fi = 0
    cnt = 0

    PlaceHolder1.Dispose()
    PlaceHolder2.Dispose()
    'Get all model
    Dim query1 As String = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT A.MacID FROM dbo.tblMachine A LEFT JOIN  dbo.tblDataHdr b on a.MacID = b.MacID where DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ORDER BY A.MACID")
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetData(query1)
    For Q As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
        'For Q As Integer = 0 To 1
        check1 = dt1.Rows(Q)(0).ToString()

'This is the slow query
        Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a  join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in ('" & check1 & "') ) Z LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur  WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in ('" & check1 & "') group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName")

        Dim mychart As Chart = New Chart
        ' Dim myplace As PlaceHolder = New PlaceHolder
        Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea
        Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend

        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)
        Dim x As String() = New String(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim y As Integer() = New Integer(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            ' y(i) = dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString()
            y(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(2))
        Next

        'Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection(myConnectionString)
        'Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection)
        'mychart.Width = Unit.Pixel(Session("sw") - 100)
        'mychart.Height = Unit.Pixel((Session("sh") / 2) - 88)

        mychart.Width = 600
        mychart.Height = 400

        mychart.ChartAreas.Clear()
        mychart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1")

        mychart.Series.Clear()
        mychart.Series.Add(0)
        mychart.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)

        mychart.Titles.Clear()
        mychart.Titles.Add("[" & Q + 1 & "] " & check1.ToString.ToUpper)
        mychart.Titles(0).Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Titles(0).BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise
        mychart.Titles(0).ForeColor = Color.Black

        mychart.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
        '  mychart.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
        mychart.Series(0).LegendText = "#VALX"
        mychart.Series(0)("BarLabelStyle") = "Center"
        mychart.Series(0)("pointWidth") = "1"
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).Label = "#PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowColor = Color.Gray
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowOffset = 10

        mychart.Series(0).LabelBackColor = Drawing.Color.Cornsilk
        mychart.Series(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold)

        'Chart1.Series(0).LabelToolTip = "#LABEL Percent: #PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).LegendToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True

        mychart.Series(0).CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=LightToDark"
        'new
        Chart1.Series(0).CustomProperties = "PieLabelStyle=Outside"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").BorderDashStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
        mychart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).BorderColor = Color.Black

        mychart.PaletteCustomColors = {Drawing.Color.Black, Drawing.Color.LightGray, Drawing.Color.Blue, Drawing.Color.Yellow, Drawing.Color.Red, Drawing.Color.Orange, Drawing.Color.Green}

        mychart.Legends.Clear()
        mychart.Legends.Add(0)
        'Chart1.Legends(0).Enabled = True
        ''Chart1.Legends(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGreenplace
        mychart.Legends(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Legends(0).Docking = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Bottom
        'Chart1.Legends(0).Alignment = Drawing.StringAlignment.Center
        'Chart1.Legends(0).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent

        mychart.DataBind()

        'myplace.Visible = True
        If (Q + 1) Mod 2 <> 0 Then
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(mychart)
            ' Dim spacer As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl("<p />")
            ' PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(spacer)
        End If
        'Exit For
        If (Q + 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then

            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(mychart)
            'Dim spacer As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl("<p />")
            ' PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(spacer)

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see exactly where it's slow? Also, what is the network latency between your web-server and the database server? And why are you using OLE-DB to connect to SQL Server instead of the native `SqlClient` ADO.NET library?

Comment: Which query did you time and how? It looks like there’s one initial one and then one per row, which is a common source of performance problems.

Comment: I timed the SQL at `Dim query as String` the second SQL string. I'll highlight it for you. The 1st one is to detect which machine is active for today and use its findings on the 2nd query.

Comment: Additionally, I placed a breakpoint on `check1 = dt1.Rows(Q)(0).ToString()` so that every time it loops back to create another pie chart I can press F5 to continue so I can count the time taken for a pie chart to be created. In the end some took less than a second while others took 2 seconds or so. I suppose the only way to reduce the time to create is to have it create multiple pie charts at once instead of one-by-one. Is that doable?